# I don't know what to do my calender code

Tags: c++, c, calendar

I am currently making a calendar algorithm and there is a question about it.
I would like to ask the calendar about changing the first day of the month on the calendar.

This is my calendar code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int days(int year, int month)
{
    int days, i;
    for (i = 1; i<month; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10 || i == 12)
        {
            days = days + 31;
        }
        else if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 11) 
        {
            days = days + 30;
        }
        else if (i == 2) 
        {
            days = days + 28;
        }
    }
    days = days + 365 * (year - 1980);
   return days;
}

int leapyear(int year, int month)
{
    int i;
    i = (year - 1977) / 4;
    if (year % 4 == 0 && month>2)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int weekday(int days)
{
    int i;
    i = days % 7;
    return i;
}

void calendar(int year, int month, int week)
{
    int i, j, k, d, cal[42] = { 0 };
    char m[12][10] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Agust", "September", "Octorber", "November", "December" };

    switch (month)
    {
       case 1: d = 31;
               break;
       case 2:
           {
               if ((year % 4) == 0) d = 29;
               else d = 28;
           }
           break;
       case 3: d = 31;
           break;
       case 4: d = 30;
           break;
       case 5: d = 31;
           break;
       case 6: d = 30;
           break;
       case 7: d = 31;
           break;
       case 8: d = 31;
           break;
       case 9: d = 30;
           break;
       case 10: d = 31;
           break;
       case 11: d = 30;
           break;
       case 12: d = 31;
           break;
    }

    printf("     < %d %s >\n", year, m[month - 1]);
    printf("===========================\n");
    printf("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");
    j = 1;
    for (i = (week + 2) % 7; i<(d + (week + 2) % 7); i++)
    {
        cal[i] = j;
        j++;
    }
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<7; j++)
        {
            if (cal[k] == 0)
            {
                printf("    ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%3d ", cal[k]);
            }
            k++;
        }

        if (i<5)
        {
            printf("\n---------------------------\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n===========================\n");
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int year, month, total_days, week;
    char YN = 'Y';
    do
    {
        printf("entered year and month with 1980 ~ 2030.(EX) :2003 5)\n");
        scanf_s("%d %d", &year, &month);
        if (year >= 1980 && year <= 2030 && month >= 1 && month <= 12)
        {
            printf("Your entered %dYear %dMonth.\n", year, month);
            total_days = days(year, month) + leapyear(year, month);
            week = weekday(total_days);
            calendar(year, month, week);
        }
        printf("Retry It?(Y/N):");
        YN = _getche();
        printf("\n");
    } while (YN != 'N');
}
```

I hope these results come out:

```
 < 2003 May >

Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat    
                  1   2   3    
  4   5   6   7   8   9  10    
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17    
 18  19  20  21  22  23  24    
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31


 Retry It?(Y/N):
```

Comment: `if ((year % 4) == 0) d = 29;`, really? Never, ever, write your own code dealing with time and dates.

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: @Art writing your own code dealing with date and time is OK as an exercise.

Comment: A leap year is a leap year regardless of the month.  Either your function named `leapyear()` is misnamed or you are confused about how leap years behave.  Note that although the years between 1901 and 2099 obey the simple 'year divisible by 4 means leap year' rule, this does not apply to either 1900 or 2100.  You have to use a more complex formula, dealing with years divisible by 100 and divisible by 400.

Comment: See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) — hint: neither the standard answer nor the portable answer is `void`.  You should also avoid dual-tagging questions with C and C++.  You're learning one of the languages; don't tag questions with the other.

Comment: Please use only a C11 standard compliant C compiler. `conio.h` is outdated and not going to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the variable `days` in the `days` function.

In C local variables are not automatically initialized to zero. If you don't initialize them, they contain un undetermined value.

So just write:

```
int days = 0, i;
```

or better

```
int days = 0;

for (int i = 1; i<month; i++)
   ...
```

I didn't check for other errors or problems, but with the correction the program apparently works fine.